# Memory leak in Controllers in PlayFramework?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I have this very simple controller.

```
package controllers.WebService

import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}

object TestLeak extends Controller {
  def index = Action {
    Ok((1 to 100000).mkString)
  }
}
```

I open it with my browser and mem consumption in my system is 2516MB.
Every time i refresh the page memory goes up 1-2MB on each refresh. You may say it's the browser's fault but i hit it from another PC and same results. Also ab bench confirms it. -c 100 -n 1000 launches memory consumption at 600mb.

**And that memory allocation never goes down**

Using System.gc() solves the problem but then I have really low performance. What is going on?

Same problem with Akka.future and scala.future and async. No other imports or trait are included. just what you see.

I have this problem for a while now and cannot deploy to Heroku without System.gc(). Any solutions?

UPDATE
Actually JAVA_OPTS are not used by heroku (silly me) you have to declare it to Procfile

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS} ... 

JAVA_OPTS: -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

Not memory consumption never goes above 500 (heroku limit)

Thanks you the time eveyone

Comment: it's not a memory leak if memory go back to inital state after GC, you may want to tweek JVM gc parameters to avoid performance issue

Comment: "Java is like Alzheimer's - it starts slowly and then takes all your memory". JVM is known for hogging memory and not giving it back to the system. Until it actually slows down your app, tuning GC may actually harm it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is play related. This seems to me like normal behaviour. The JVM does not collect garbage directly after the request, it decides on its own (based on the gc settings, that can be modified) when it will collect. Did your application ever crash because it was out of memory? You should attach jconsole to it and then run ab with a large number of request and you will see, that the memory is eventually freed.

Comment: thanks. Actually it had wrong params for -Xmx . Thanks for your input